# Npgsql: column t.Value does not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Я вызываю хранимую процедуру и получаю исключение

> Npgsql.PostgresException: "42703: column t.Value does not exist
> POSITION: 8"

Объявление процедуры выглядит так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION survey.get_survey(uid text, usrid integer)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
```

Я вызываю процедуру следующим образом:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM survey.get_survey({0}, {1})";
var data = Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(sql, surveyId, userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Проблема заключается в том, что не ясно, что это за такая колонка t.Value. Ведь в самой процедуре не используется ни одна колонка с таким названием.

В процедуре используются встроенные функции json_agg и json_build_object.
Сама процедура 100% рабочая. Значит ошибка на моей стороне.

Вопрос: если кто-то знает, что может быть причиной исключения или у кого-то была подобная ошибка, напишите, пожалуйста, как вы ее решили. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
string sql = "SELECT survey.get_survey({0}, {1})";
string jsonString = Database.SqlQueryRaw<string>(sql, surveyId, userId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ИМХО более правильный вариант в этом случае передать пустой JSON вместо пустой строки '{}'